# How do I get terminal to print command history with timestamps for all commands

Tags: zsh, macos, command-history

I'm trying to get my terminal (macOS) to print the previous commands that I've used, as well as the timestamps to go with them.

I know that if I use `history man`, it will give me a list of the past 1000 or so, and if I use `history -E`, it will give commands with timestamps though only about 20 or so.

Is there any way to concatenate them, so I get the timestamps for all?

Comment: I retagged your question, deleting the [tag:terminal] tag as it's the shell, not the terminal, that stores the command-line history.  I also tagged it with [tag:zsh] as this is the default login shell on macOS nowadays.  If you are using some other shell, then please change the [tag:zsh] to the appropriate tag for your shell.

Answer (score 4):

In the `zsh` shell, to get *all* the history for the current shell session with timestamps ("in the European `dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm` format"), use

```bash
history -E 1
```

The `1` at the end signifies that you'd like to see the history from the first (to the last) entry.

Note that to get the shell to store the timestamps in the history file (`$HISTFILE`), you need to enable the `EXTENDED_HISTORY` shell option with

```bash
setopt EXTENDED_HISTORY
```

... in your `~/.zshrc` file (the option takes effect with the next new shell session).  History entries saved without setting this option will *not* be saved with their timestamps.

---

The `history man` command you used in the question will show all history entries since the most recent line containing the string `man`, however many entries this may be.  You may combine `history -E` and `history man` as `history -E man` to get timestamped history entries since the most recent entry containing `man`.

By default, `history` outputs the most recent 16 command-line history entries.

Comment: Hey that seems to have worked the only issue is that is give every command the same timestamp of the current date and time

Comment: @AlekNaomieBurtPilon This is likely because you do not have the `EXTENDED_HISTORY` shell option set (`setopt EXTENDED_HISTORY` in your `~/.zshrc` file).  Timestamps will not be saved properly until you enable this option.  I will add more to my answer.

Comment: Great look forward to the rest

Comment: I followed the instruction you recommended and saved the option to my ~.zshrc file though I still have the same problem of terminal ascribing all commands in the history file to whatever the current date and time is. could it be that it didn't save that information

Comment: @AlekNaomieBurtPilon The option takes effect upon starting a new shell session, and it will not magically add the correct timestamps to old history entries that were already stored before.

Comment: ahh okay that's really what I wanted to know. well at least is should be implemented now thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**This is for running with a Bash terminal, not zsh**

You can set HISTTIMEFORMAT.

```
If the HISTTIMEFORMAT variable is set and not null, its value is used
as a format string for strftime(3) to print the time stamp associated
with each displayed history entry.  No time stamps are printed otherwise.
```

So for example

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T "
history
```

For my example I did in terminal with this result...

```
 2118  02/21/2023 01:00:54 PM history 
 2119  02/21/2023 01:01:47 PM export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T "
 2120  02/21/2023 01:01:48 PM history
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply I also tried what you put into terminal and all I get back in the number of the command and the command

Comment: @AlekNaomieBurtPilon can you try without using `export`? Also maybe try doing `HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T "` just trying a different format.